# Any solution for Angular JS with ng- tags

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I do love to use AngularJs in my Multiple Pages Laravel Application.

Since am using Laravel Blade Template Engine, I don't seem to like the idea of including Angular Tags to cluster my blade templates

Example

```
<div ng-controller="TodoController">
      <span>@{{remaining()}} of @{{todos.length}} remaining</span>
      [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
      <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
          <span class="done-@{{todo.done}}">@{{todo.text}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30"
               placeholder="add new todo here">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
      </form>
    </div>
```

NB: `@{{todo.done}}` is a way to tell Blade to ignore the curly braces

Is there a way i can use AngularJS without including tags like ng-controller, ng-repeat:

**The reason why i would like to do without the tags includes:**
1. in the future i might decide to use another JS framework such as Emberjs or any other better one so, i have to find all ng- tags in my blade files an remove them

2. I just don't like to tell the world, "Hey am using AngularJS" not that am not proud of it but based on what my clients need and security reasons too.

Thanks in advance for your expert response

Comment: If you want to use Angular, just use Angular.

Comment: It is a client side technology, so there's no way around "telling the world" how you're doing it.

Comment: @popovitsj I get the point. tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **may** be able to avoid using ng- directives. However, it's a *really bad* practice, and it will probably be frowned upon for ages.

You just have to restrain yourself from using controllers, then use a single `run` call to populate the rootScope. Then you only have to manually bootstrap the application:

```
var module = angular.module( 'myApp', [ ] ).run( function ( $rootScope ) {
    $rootScope.myVariable = 'hello world';
} );

angular.element( document ).ready( function ( ) {
    angular.bootstrap( document, [ 'myApp' ] );
} );
```

---

Now, why you should not do this:

- The Angular frameworks uses directives as primary component. Not using them is a really bad idea, because using them is actually the whole point of using Angular.
- As said in comment, everyone is already able to know what you are using - and if they are looking at the source code, they will certainly also look at your js libraries.

Answer (score 0):

*As one of the simplest solutions*. You can change start and end symbols of angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

And then, your template would looks like:

```
[[ todo.text ]]
```

For more info [ng-docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)